# Can I travel to Italy after the my residency card renewal receipt expires?

Tags: italy, visa-expiration, bangladesh, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am from Bangladesh. I came Bangladesh in March with Ricevuta from the Permesso di Soggiorno kit. I thought I will back Italy in July but Italian government has banned flight from Bangladesh till 30 July. Now Ricevuta date has expired .

Can I travel after my Italy after the Ricevuta from the Permesso di Soggiorno kit expires?

Comment: Ricevuta for what?

Comment: Probably the reciept (Ricevuta) from the **Permesso di Soggiorno kit**.

Comment: For Permesso di Soggiorno .

Comment: You should contact the Italian Consulate.